# How to change marker labels in anychart horizontal gauge?

Tags: javascript, angular, anychart

I am using anychart for creating a percentage horizontal gauge.

And i want to change the  marker information to show what i want.

I found nothing on the documentation about it.

I'm using the javascript anychart playground (link below).
The final implementation is on Angular 5.

The original code : 
https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/GAUGE_Linear_04

(Optional) The typescript method :

```
createAnyChartsCustomGauges() {
let array = [];
    this.listItem.forEach(item => {
      // Gauge type and data
      const gauge = anychart.gauges.linear();
      gauge.layout('horizontal');
      // Set the data
      gauge.data([item.percent]); //number

      // Create the custom scale bar
      const scaleBarre = gauge.scaleBar(0);
      // color and style setting
      const colorScale = anychart.scales.ordinalColor().ranges([
        {
          from: 0,
          to: 25,
          color: ['#D81E05', '#EB7A02'],
        },
        {
          from: 25,
          to: 50,
          color: ['#EB7A02', '#FFD700'],
        },
        {
          from: 50,
          to: 75,
          color: ['#FFD700', '#CAD70b'],
        },
        {
          from: 75,
          to: 100,
          color: ['#CAD70b', '#2AD62A'],
        },
      ]);
      scaleBarre.width('5%');
      scaleBarre.offset('31.5%');
      scaleBarre.colorScale(colorScale);

      // Add a marker pointer
      const marker = gauge.marker(0);
      marker.offset('31.5%');
      marker.type('triangle-up');
      marker.zIndex(10);
      marker.labels().format('{%data[0]}%');
      // Add a scale
      const scale = gauge.scale();
      scale.minimum(0);
      scale.maximum(100);
      scale.maxTicksCount(10);

      // Add an axis
      const axis = gauge.axis();
      axis.minorTicks(true);
      axis.minorTicks().stroke('#cecece');
      axis.width('1%');
      axis.offset('29.5%');
      axis.orientation('top');

      // format axis labels
      axis.labels().format('{%value}%');

      // set paddings
      gauge.padding([0, 20]);

      array.push(gauge);

    });
  }
```

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deCBn.png) : 
{ 
  Pointer 0
  Value 63
}

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEOBL.png) : 
{
  Value 63%
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gugateider was absolutely right! Also, if you don't want to use HTML styling for tooltip and disable tooltip title and separator, you can use the code below:

```
  gauge.tooltip().title(false);
  gauge.tooltip().separator(false);
  gauge.tooltip().format("Value: {%value}%");
```

Comment: Hello,thanks a lot ! Your solution works perfectly on my example ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `format()` methods of the [Tooltip](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Tooltip) class.
There's a similar example on [Any charts playground](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/CS_Tooltip_15)

```
// enable HTML for tooltips
chart.tooltip().useHtml(true);

// tooltip settings
var tooltip = gauge.tooltip();
tooltip.positionMode("point");
tooltip.format("Value: <b>${%value} %</b>");
```

Try that and see if works?

Comment: Hello, i've tried it on my description playground, it doesn't seems to work. But nevermind, an don't worry, i will take the @AnyChart Support way. Thanks for your answer.